# dotnet core 1.0.1 preview2 freeze/hangs on dotnet test?

Tags: .net-core

On some systems, and not others, at my office, it seems dotnet core is unstable, perhaps something else  (visual studio 2017 rc?) is interfering, and "dotnet test" commands which work elsewhere, are hanging (no output, no tests run, just freezes):

```
xUnit.net .NET CLI test runner (64-bit .NET Core win10-x64)
  Discovering: x.y.UnitTests
  Discovered:  x.y.UnitTests
  Starting:    x.y.UnitTests
```

I am trying to figure out what the cause of this is. It blocks CI and developers.  I believe it may be possible to isolate and fix, and I'm asking this in case anyone sees it, or if I figure it out, I'll answer it so others who get stuck here can get unstuck.

Comment: It seems impossible to debug this case, and only SOME xunit projects are crashing, and only on SOME machines.

Comment: Having the exact same issue. Did you find a solution or a workaround?

Comment: https://xkcd.com/979/

Answer (score 0):

xUnit support for dotnet core projects requires very specific versions of dotnet core, dotnet core CLI, xunit, and dotnet-test-xunit as defined in the xUnit [documentation](http://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-dotnet-core).  I too have experienced the behavior you describe when attempting to run tests in Visual Studio Team Services where I unfortunately don't control the .NET Core CLI version.  The same tests run without issue on my local machine, where I have confirmed that the xunit package versions and dotnet tooling versions match those supported by xUnit.  I suspect that the machines you are experiencing the issues on do not have the supported dotnet tooling and xunit package versions.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my very similar issue. I used anynch methods in my tests and accessed the result with .Result. This can cause a [deadlock situation in x-unit](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). Instead try declaring your methods with async and then using await to get the result. I found the solution on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32010851/7683711)

Answer (score -2):

Following xUnit docs I've switched to using **dotnet xunit** command instead of **dotnet test**. Also I had to specify extra parameter **-parallel none**. That solved my issue.